# Equivalence for quantifications

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Considering:

**(1)** $(\exists x)(E(x) \land (\forall y)(E(y)\rightarrow M(x,y)))$

There are equivalences that say:
$\lnot(\forall x)  A \equiv (\exists x)  \lnot A$

$\lnot(\exists x)  A \equiv (\forall x)  \lnot A$

So, if I want to express (1) only with the "forall" quantifier I got:

**(2)** $\lnot(\forall x)(E(x) \rightarrow \lnot((\forall y)(E(y)\rightarrow M(x,y))))$

Is this ok? What happens with the $\lnot((\forall y)(E(y)\rightarrow M(x,y))))$ part???

Is the same as $\lnot((\forall y))\lnot((E(y)\rightarrow M(x,y)))$  ??

More over, if I want quantifiers at the start of the expression, could be (1) directly expressed as:

**(3)** $(\exists x)(\forall y)((E(x) \land (E(y))\rightarrow M(x,y)))$ ??

Or something can like (3) only be obtained coming from (2) ??:

$\lnot(\forall x)(\forall y)((E(x) \land (E(y))\rightarrow M(x,y)))$

---

**EDIT:**
Here i go again, are the next expressions equivalent?:

1. $(\exists x)(E(x) \land (\forall y)(E(y)\rightarrow M(x,y)))$
2. $\lnot(\forall x)\lnot(E(x) \land (\forall y)(E(y)\rightarrow M(x,y)))$
3. $\lnot(\forall x)(\lnot(E(x)) \lor \lnot((\forall y)(E(y)\rightarrow M(x,y))))$
4. $\lnot(\forall x)(E(x) \rightarrow \lnot((\forall y)(E(y)\rightarrow M(x,y))))$
5. $\lnot(\forall x)(E(x) \rightarrow \lnot((\forall y)(\lnot(E(y))\lor M(x,y))))$
6. $\lnot(\forall x)(E(x) \rightarrow (\exists y)\lnot((\lnot(E(y))\lor M(x,y))))$
7. $\lnot(\forall x)(E(x) \rightarrow (\exists y)(E(y)\land \lnot(M(x,y))))$

This rule is valid?:
$\lnot((\forall x)  A) \equiv \lnot(\forall x)  A \equiv (\exists x)  \lnot A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both 2 and 3 are correct. 3 can be obtained from 1 directly. Not sure what the $\lnot((\forall y))\lnot((E(y)\rightarrow M(x,y)))$ means -why the double parentheses? If you ignore those, then it's just $\exists y(E(y)\rightarrow M(x,y))$, which is true, but weaker than what you started with.

Comment: Is not $\exists y(E(y) \land \lnot M(x,y))$ ??. According to $\lnot(\forall x)  A \equiv (\exists x)  \lnot A$

Comment: As you may see, im confused with: $\lnot((\forall y)(E(y)\rightarrow M(x,y)))$. ¿Is the same as: $\lnot((\forall y))(E(y)\rightarrow M(x,y))$ ?. (Note the parentheses). So the negation is only applied on the cuantifier?

Comment: There is no such thing as negation only applied to the quantifier.

Comment: See mi edit please.

Comment: Everything in your edit is correct. But why do you use so many parentheses? And what does the edit have to do with negation only applied to the quantifier?

Comment: Oh well, in class we use for example $(\forall x)$ instead of $\forall x$, and i know there are other parhenteses not really needed, but i think they are not harmful anyway. And mi confusion came from: $\lnot((\forall x)  A) \equiv \lnot(\forall x)  A \equiv (\exists x)  \lnot A$. But if that equivalence is correct i think i understand now. Thanks.